# Data binding no error but could not the see the binded output

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to learn WPF and I am stuck with the very initial binding example. **I want to see the text in the textbox from the property present in the code.** I have seen some relevant questions and I have tried their answers but unfortunately none of them fits my need. Moreover if someone could tell me some nice tutorials that starts from basic and proceed to advanced level. I am looking in msdn tutorials but I find them very complex (or too much text) making things more complicated.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{     
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Name = "Dummy";
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;


        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `Name` hides the `Name` property of the base class (and Visual Studio warns you about this). You're setting the new property, while the Binding in XAML uses the base class property.

Choose a different property name:

```
public string MyName { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    MyName = "Dummy";
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyName}" />
```

Comment: The next step is to use a view model class, as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem create a new class:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Name = "Dummy";
    }

}
```

And change the code behind to this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then it should work.

You can find tutorials in Youtube when you search for MVVM.

Comment: Yes this also works but I could mark only one as an answer and I dont have enough points to vote you. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: No Proplem :-) I'm glad I could help you